# Pandas groupby: get product value for each individual group

Tags: python, pandas, vector, multiplication, pandas-groupby

This might sound a little stupid so apologies in advance. I have dataframe such that:

```
            value       date
0           1.0         2010-01-31
1           0.3         2010-02-28
2           1.6         2011-03-31
3           2.5         2011-04-30
4          -1.0         2012-05-31
5          -0.3         2012-06-30
6           1.6         2013-07-31
```

I want to group it by year and the apply the follwoing formula to each group
    [[(1 + v1) * (1 + v2) * (1 + v3) *....(1 +vn)] - 1] * 100
So the operation is to add 1 to each individual element within a group, then take its product, then subtract 1 from the resulting value and then multiply that by 100

But when i do this

```
df.groupby(a.date.dt.year).apply(lambda x: (1+x['value'])).prod()
```

I get a single value ( I think it gets the product of everything. How do I get the product for each group (a single value for each year)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it outside the `groupby` `apply` function , with `assign`

```
df.assign(val=df.value+1).groupby(df.date.dt.year).val.prod()-1
Out[800]: 
date
2010    1.6
2011    8.1
2012   -1.0
2013    1.6
Name: val, dtype: float64
```

Two benefits:

1, More easy to understand

2, More efficient

Comment: I can always trust you to answer my questions :) Thank you. But I am just curious as to whether it spossible to do it with groupby. Doing groupby(df.date.dt.year).sum() gives individual values for each group but not prod(). Is there another function or argument to do that?

Comment: @Fizi I think for your own solution you just need to change to 
(put prod in apply)
`df.groupby(a.date.dt.year).apply(lambda x: (1+x['value']).prod())`

Comment: @Fizi also `df.groupby(a.date.dt.year).apply(lambda x: (1+x['value']))` return value for each group, an this is  result after groupby, and if you adding .prod() at the end , which mean you want to mul the whole column together , Just a kindly reminder , groupby only follow one function , not chain function like` groupby().sum().prod()`, In your situation , `apply` is count as one function

Comment: Ah gotcha, that's helpful. Also, in your solution - can you chain the multiplication by 100 in the same command somehow. Since its a series I am first assigning it then multiplying in the next step

Comment: @Fizi `(df.assign(val=df.value+1).groupby(df.date.dt.year).val.prod()-1)*100`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167672/discussion-between-fizi-and-wen).

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby(a.date.dt.year).apply(lambda x: (1+x['value'])).prod()
```

This statement will compute the product of all the values in the respective columns. Thus only one value will be returned irrespective whether the data has been grouped according to year or not.
But if you apply the `prod()` function inside the lambda function as shown-

```
df.groupby(a.date.dt.year).apply(lambda x: (1+x['value']).prod())
```

This should give the output as you desire.